# Why does passing temporaries of eigen expressions cause access to undefined memory?

Tags: c++, eigen

In trying to track down a bug I've been able to come up with the following simple program which illustrates the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using Mat = Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 1, Eigen::AutoAlign>;

template <typename Derived>
auto Modify(const Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>& value)
    -> decltype(2*value.derived().array())
{
    return 2*value.derived().array();
}

Mat Make()
{
    Mat mat;
    mat << 2;
    return mat;
}

int main()
{
    auto mat = Make();

    std::cout
        << "first: " << Modify(mat) << std::endl
        << "second: " << Modify(Modify(mat));

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

> ```
> first: 4
> second: 3.95253e-323
> ```

running the resulting code under valgrind produces a `Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation` error.

Is there anything wrong with the above code? As the original `mat` matrix is in scope at the point where the matrix is evaluated, why does it matter that I'm creating temporaries of `Eigen::DenseBase` expressions?

I have tried compiling with Eigen 3.2.1 as well as Eigen 3.2.2 and got the same result.

Comment: @ooga http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T.C.'s answers was true but that behavior was unintended as lightweight expressions are supposed to be nested by values, not by reference. There was a little shortcoming in `ArrayWrapper` that made it nested by reference in some cases. This is now fixed in both the 3.2 and default branches. So your example works fine now.

Comment: OP claims that they used Eigen 3.2.

Comment: I definitely reproduced the problem on a freshly downloaded copy of  Eigen 3.2.2. *Edit* - Ah, I see, it's just been fixed [an hour ago](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/589ff21345fab4f8ff0d1ea75a018767aa8499cd) :)

Comment: @T.C. Is that fix you linked in 3.2.2 now, or do I need to download trunk?

Comment: @Arman You should ask @ ggael...I assume that it's not in 3.2.2.

Comment: Right, that will be in the future 3.2.3 and 3.3 release. In the meantime, you can download the 3.2 branch [there](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/downloads).

Answer (score 3):

`value.derived().array()` returns a temporary `ArrayWrapper` object. `2 * value.derived().array()` constructs an expression object, which stores a reference to that `ArrayWrapper`, but that temporary `ArrayWrapper` is destroyed right afterwards. Thus the expression object you returned from `Modify` contains a dangling reference.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you know of a way to ensure that the expression refers to the `derived()` type while still exposing the functionality of `Eigen::Array`?

Comment: @Arman Looks like [you got your wish](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/589ff21345fab4f8ff0d1ea75a018767aa8499cd) :)